# How to clear validation messages in a dijit form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, dojo

How to clear validation messages in a dijit form (widgets including validation textboxes, filtering selects, number textboxes etc without resetting the form, ie Data need to be retained but validation messages. I am looking for a kind of flush action retaining the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reset function on the form itself.

> reset(e) restores all widget values back to their init values, calls
>   onReset() which can cancel the reset by returning false,. [Resource](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dijit_form_Form_reset).

Example:

```
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){
    var form = registry.byId("yourFormId");
    form.reset(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
registry.byId(textBoxId).reset();
```

Comment: IMO reset should be applied on the form itself and not on the textBox

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.